# Entity Framework expects wrong types from stored procedure result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that - after some processing - returns the following:

```
SELECT  @PlanId     PlanId,
        @QuoteId    QuoteId,
        GETDATE()   [When]
```

@PlanId is defined as an int, @QuoteId is a bigint

I would therefore expect Entity Framework to anticipate a result row containing those types, plus a datetime, but it doesn't.

No matter how I try to persuade it the interface in the context class looks like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<long>> ProcedureName( {parameters} )
```

Is there a way I can explicitly make it expect the correct result?

[Edit]

Code to call the prodecure looks like this:

```
                using (var context = new Entities())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = context.StoredProcedureName({parameters});
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw (ex);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How are you generating procedure are you using complex type? you can also use direct biding

Comment: You must be returning a nullable int from your proc elsewhere. Have you tried looking at: SET FMTONLY ON;

Comment: I'm not using complex types, and the only SELECT statements in the procedure are the final one that returns the result and assignments

Comment: What version of EF is this?

Comment: Yes it is, in fact I found out why it's happening I think. The procedure calls other procedures which I think are interfering with the result. Will investigate more and update.

Comment: @EricEJ got me on the right track. I used `sp_describe_first_result_set` which showed that there was an issue, which turned out that my procedure was calling another one, that was returning results. I just made a silent version and called that - problem solved!